# Форматирование текста внутри Button

Tags: java, android

Есть ли вообще возможность по разному форматировать текст внутри `Button`?
Допустим, мне нужно, что бы половина текста в `Button` была красного цвета, а другая половина черного. Как это можно осуществить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Зачем вообще в таком случае использовать button? Сделайте свой элемент и добавьте для него onClickListener, вот Вам и Button.

Comment: Да, спасибо, решил задачу с помощью ListView.

Comment: не знаю, что имменно у Вас, но по Вашему вопросу можно ещё предусмотреть такое решение. Создаете файл разметки с двумя текствью в лайоуте, и класс java, с полями, которые являются этими текст вью. Устанавливаете их по айди на создании объекта этого класса, делаете некликабельными, а лайоут кликабеьным. На него вешаете слушатель. Можете в этом класса определить метод, который будет переключать цвета каждого из текст вью по вызову этого метода. Как то так